# syntax error near unexpected token `(' (possible bash bug)

Tags: bash

Maybe I've just triggered an error in bash's parser, but before filing a bugreport I wan't to ask anyways, maybe I'm just getting blind and it's not a bash bug after all ...

This is the script (ok, stripped down version of the actual one):

```
$ cat bash-parse-error.1.sh
#! /bin/sh

echo "$(
    if false
    then
            exit 0
    fi

    # echo "("
    case FOO in
            FOO)
                    echo "("
                    ;;
    esac
)"
$ ./bash-parse-error.1.sh
./bash-parse-error.1.sh: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./bash-parse-error.1.sh: line 12: `                 echo "("'
```

Now, If I de-comment the extra echo command, the script works as you would expect, printing two opening parenthesises:

```
$ cat bash-parse-error.2.sh
#! /bin/sh

echo "$(
    if false
    then
            exit 0
    fi

    echo "("
    case FOO in
            FOO)
                    echo "("
                    ;;
    esac
)"
$ ./bash-parse-error.2.sh
(
(
```

Alternatively, removing the if-false-then-exit block (doing whatever I want with the commented out echo command) will make the error go away as well:

```
$ cat bash-parse-error.3.sh
#! /bin/sh

echo "$(
    case FOO in
            FOO)
                    echo "("
                    ;;
    esac
)"
$ ./bash-parse-error.3.sh
(
```

So, is it me or is it bash?

/edit:
a) no workaround needed, already got one, thx anyways

b) #! /usr/bash obviously exhibits same problem, because

c) versions tested: 4.3.33(1) and 4.3.39(1)

Comment: Note you are using `#! /bin/sh` (a space before `/bin`).

Comment: @fedorqui: The space is allowed there. `sh` != `bash` with regard to the tag.

Comment: @choroba really? I would've thought `#! /bin/sh` wouldn't be resolved properly.

Comment: @fedorqui: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: @chepner oh yeah, I guess I jumped to the wrong conclusion there

Comment: @choroba true, "The blank after #! is optional".

Comment: What happens if you comment the `echo "$("` line in bash-parse-error-3.sh? I'm leaning to some sort of comment-related parser bug.

Comment: Also, `bash-parse-error-1.sh` prints one `(` as expected in `bash` 4.3; this seems to be a fixed bug.

Comment: pluse-uno for an interesting problem! haven't seen this one before. Can you have **any** commented lines (not just `echo "("`) ? Good luck.

Comment: `echo "moo"("bar"` is a syntax error as well.  I don't see how this is really different.

Comment: As edited, this question answers itself (and is thus no longer a question).

Comment: @tripleee: "$(...)" takes precedence over "$(" and ")". So "$(echo ")")" is *intended* to substitute to ")"

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Shall I edit it back?

Comment: @shellter: Not sure if I understand you correctly. I just copy pasted the other echo command.

Comment: Yes. Keeping questions and answers separate allows them to be voted on, selected, and moderated individually; it's very much encouraged for the person who asked a question to add an answer themselves (with the "add answer" button) when they come on a solution that no 3rd-party answer includes (and if you get rep from separate upvoting of your question and your answer, then it's taken as given that you earned both parts).

Comment: done, is a question again.

Comment: I don't see anything in the patch levels between 4.3.33/39 and 4.3.42 that looks like it should affect this (but the patches don't have explanations so I could certainly have missed something).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of bash are you seeing this with? (I see it with `3.2.25(1)-release` but not with `4.1.2(1)-release` or `4.3.42(1)-release`.)

Using the optional `(` on the case statement works around the problem as well.

An issue about this was filed for shellcheck as https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/issues/482 which references the [Command Substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst) Bash Hackers Wiki page which discusses it too (as a "Construct to avoid").

Though technically that issue is with a closing `)` not an opening one as you've found here.

bash 4.2.46(1)-release from CentOS 7 fails on `.1.sh` but works on the other two. And adding the `(` fixes `.1.sh` there as well.